# Pushing down aggregation to Cassandra when querying from Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I've got a Cassandra table looking like this:

```
my_keyspace.my_table (
    part_key_col_1 text,
    clust_key_col_1 int,
    clust_key_col_2 text,
    value_col_1 text
    PRIMARY KEY (part_key_col_1, clust_key_col_1, clust_key_col_2, value_col_1)
```

I'm looking to retrieve tha maximum value of `clust_key_col_1` for each `part_key_col_1`, where I also want a filter on `clust_key_col_1`. In CQL I can achieve this using:

```
SELECT
    part_key_col_1
    max(clust_key_col_1)
FROM my_table
WHERE clust_key_col_1 < 123
GROUP BY part_key_col_1
ALLOW FILTERING
```

Even though I need to use `ALLOW FILTERING` the query is super fast, I got roughly 1 000 000 unique `part_key_col_1` and for each `part_key_col_1` I got less than 5000 unique `clust_key_col_1` .

My problem comes when I try to get the same data in Spark using Spark Cassandra Connector. I've tried the following in Spark:

```
cassandra_df = (
    spark.read
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
    .options(table='my_table', keyspace='my_keyspace')
    .load()
    .filter(f.col('clust_key_col_1') < 123)
    .groupBy(f.col('part_key_col_1'))
    .agg(
        f.max('clust_key_col_1')
    )
)
```

But the Physical-plan ends up being:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(2) HashAggregate(keys=[part_key_col_1#144], functions=[max(clust_key_col_1#145)])
+- Exchange hashpartitioning(part_key_col_1#144, 20)
   +- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[part_key_col_1#144], functions=[partial_max(clust_key_col_1#145)])
      +- *(1) Scan org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation [part_key_col_1#144,clust_key_col_1#145] PushedFilters: [*LessThan(clust_key_col_1,123)], ReadSchema: struct<part_key_col_1:string,clust_key_col_1:int>
```

Meaning the filter for `clust_key_col_1` gets pushed down to Cassandra, but the grouping and the aggregation does not. Instead all the data (with `clust_key_col_1 < 123`) gets loaded into Spark and aggregated in Spark. Can I somehow "push down" the grouping/aggregation to Cassandra and only load the `max(clust_key_col_1)` for each `part_key_col_1`) to reduce the load on Spark and the network? Right now Spark will load 1 000 000 * 5000 rows instead of 1 000 000 rows.

Comment: what version of Spark?

Comment: @AlexOtt Spark 2.4.7 with SCC 2.5

Comment: Maybe pass a query instead of a table?